# cp {fileList}* dir_name where fileList contains files and directories

Tags: bash, directory, cp

So I'm working on an assignment which requires me to write a shell script in bash which will take 2 existing directory names as its first 2 arguments and copy the contents of the 2 into the directory specified by the 3rd argument. This works when the 2 directories only contain regular files but if they contain any directories I've come across a "cp: cannot stat '{all the file names}'" error. How can fix this error?

This is my entire script. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
alias error='echo "usage: cpdirs.sh source_directory1 source_directory2 dest_directory"'

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
    error
    exit
fi

if [ -d $1 -a -d $2 ]
then
    ls1=`ls "$1"`
    ls2=`ls "$2"`
else
    error
    exit
fi

CD=`pwd`

if [ ! -d "$3" ]
then
    mkdir "$3"
fi

cd "$3"
thrd=`pwd`
cd "$CD"
cd "$1"

ls1=${ls1//
/ }

if [ -n "$ls1" ]
then
    cp -R "$ls1" "$thrd"
fi

cd "$CD"
cd "$2"

ls2=${ls2//
/ }

if [ -n "$ls2" ]
then
    cp -R "$ls2" "$thrd"
fi
```

Comment: I fail to understand, why your script is any more complicated than `cp -r "$1"/* "$2"/* "$3"` (+ sanity checks). Could you specify more?

Comment: It's for an assignment so obviously i could right a simple one but i have to have checks and output for other possible user errors the way my professor wants us to

Comment: also this is my first experience with bash shell scripts at all so there's that

Comment: UNIX filenames can contain both spaces and newlines, so you absolutely can't use either newlines or spaces to separate filenames safely. The only characters that can't be used in filenames are `/` (which, obviously, _can_ be contained in path specifiers) and the NUL byte.

Comment: @JohnTracy if you want (or must) venture deeper into bash scripting, you should check out the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (where "advanced" is a misnomer, since it targets beginners, too).

Comment: @Boldewyn, I actually emphatically and strongly reject the suggestion of the ABS as a good guide -- it's only very occasionally maintained, and makes a habit of showcasing bad practices while demonstrating features. Someone who's an expert knows when those examples aren't meant to be followed literally, but people who are there to learn don't.

Comment: @Boldewyn, ...back when I was a channel regular in Freenode's #bash, helping people unlearn things they got from the ABS was half the job. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is far better-maintained.

Comment: OK, I see the point for not letting beginners learn unattended from ABS. And yes, the maintenance interval and quality of the examples are sometimes far from optimal. (But still, it is a large resource of annotated solutions to common problems. So, the gist is, ABS yes, but with huge content warning for beginners.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual files to be copied need to be passed as individual parameters to `cp`. You're passing a space-separated list of filenames **inside a single parameter** -- meaning that `cp` is trying to find a single file with a name that results from concatenating together all the individual filenames in your directory (as those names are munged by `ls`).

Short answer: Don't do it this way at all. [Don't use `ls` programatically](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and particularly [don't try to put multiple arguments in a single scalar variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). If you want to store multiple filenames in a variable, use an array:

```
filenames=( * )
```

...expanded as:

```
cp -- "${filenames[@]}" /path/to/destination
```